# Deleting items in list with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following `function`, which fills the `list` with items. But I also would like to create a `function`, which clears the whole content of the list, how should I do it?

Here is the function itself:

```
function listFiller() {
    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(guessedWord));
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" - "));
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(seconds));
    list.appendChild(entry);
}
```

Also, how could I specify that the items should be added to the top of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function clearList() {
    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    while(list.lastChild) {
        list.removeChild(list.lastChild);
    }
}
```